# Always returns to main fragment onBackpressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, back-stack

I have implemented Navigation Drawer in Activity. I have 3-4 fragments in my app.

Let's say there are 3 fragments : **Fragment_1, Fragment_2, Fragment_3**

When I start my app, Fragment_1 is loaded and i go to another fragments using navigation drawer.

So it's like

**Fragment_1 -> Fragment_2 -> Fragment_3 -> Fragment_1 -> Fragment_3**

Now, when I press back button it's like

**Fragment_3 -> Fragment_1 -> Fragment_3 -> Fragment_2 -> Fragment_1**

> But, I want something like if wherever i am when i press back key, i
>   navigate back to Fragment_1 always.

I am using below code to navigate to another fragment :-

```
nav_menu_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                DashboardFragment dashboardFragment = new DashboardFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainContainer, dashboardFragment, dashboardFragment.getClass().getName());
                break;

            case 1:
                ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainContainer, profileFragment, profileFragment.getClass().getName());
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                break;

            case 2:
                ContactUsFragment contactUsFragment = new ContactUsFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainContainer, contactUsFragment, contactUsFragment.getClass().getName());
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                break;

            case 3:
                AboutUsFragment aboutUsFragment = new AboutUsFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainContainer, aboutUsFragment, aboutUsFragment.getClass().getName());
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
});
```

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if(!(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mainContainer) instanceof DashboardFragment))
        {
            DashboardFragment dashboardFragment = new DashboardFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainContainer, dashboardFragment, dashboardFragment.getClass().getName());
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Use this method into main activity will solve your problem.

Comment: got this error :- Operator "!" can not be applied to "android.app.fragment"

Comment: not working, still the same form as 
 Fragment_3 -> Fragment_1 -> Fragment_3 -> Fragment_2 -> Fragment_1

Comment: remove `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);` from your java code.

Comment: I Updated your code copy and paste your code in your application and run it.

Comment: I already try that code, it is not working, It causes closing app not start dashboardFragment

Answer (score 0):

I've changed next lines in your code and it worked just fine

Replace:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainContainer, dashboardFragment, 
dashboardFragment.getClass().getName());
```

With:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContainer,
dashboardFragment).commit();
```